# Deleting element in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have two view pages. On both pages I have a list of items with a picture of a star next to it. On the 1st page, I can click the star and it will turn blue or gray. On the 2nd page, if the star is blue and I click on it I want to delete the parent div associated it. It does delete it when I reload the whole page but doesn't delete it immediately. How can I delete it from the page immediately and without clicking the reload button?

This is in my result.html.erb where I want to delete the parent div. To be clear, when I click on the star associated with the diamond div, I want to delete that whole div and leave the pearl div alone.

```
<div id="result">
  <div class="diamond">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.website.com">diamond</a>
    <img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-blue.png" alt="star pic">
  </div>
  <div class="pearl">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.website.com">pearl</a>
    <img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-blue.png" alt="star pic">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is in my application.js

```
var favoriteGems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gems")) || []

function changeStar(){
  if($(this).attr("src") == "/assets/star-gray.png"){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
    favoriteGems.push($(this).closest("div").first().text().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems))
  }
  else if ($(this).attr("src") == "/assets/star-blue.png"){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
    favoriteGems = favoriteGems.filter(item => item !== $(this).closest("div").first().text().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems))
    $("#result").remove("."+item)
    $("#result").show()
  }
}

$(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)
```

I've tried

```
$("#result").remove("."+item)
location.reload()
```

and that doesn't work either.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` in `$("#result").remove("."+item)` may not be the value you want. You can add `var item = $(this).closest("div").first().text().replace(/\s+/g, '')` before this line.

You can refactor `changeStar`further like this:

```
function changeStar() {
  var targetItem = $(this).closest("div").first().text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
  var favoriteGems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gems")) || [];
  if($(this).attr("src") === "/assets/star-gray.png"){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
    favoriteGems.push(targetItem)
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems))
  }
  else if ($(this).attr("src") === "/assets/star-blue.png"){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
    favoriteGems = favoriteGems.filter(item => item !== targetItem)
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems))
    $("#result").remove("." + targetItem)
    $("#result").show()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was the wrong value. I also switched $("#result").show() to location.reload(). And now it's doing what I want it to do. For some reason $("#result").show() wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To be sincere this looks a bit cryptic, but why not call simply

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

? And clean a bit the html structure & js

```
<div id="result">
<div class="diamond">
  <a target="_blank" href="www.website.com">diamond</a>
  <img class="star-pic blue-star" src="/assets/star-blue.png" alt="star pic" data-info="diamond">
</div>
<div class="pearl">
  <a target="_blank" href="www.website.com">pearl</a>
  <img class="star-pic blue-star" src="/assets/star-blue.png" alt="star pic" data-info="pearl">
</div>
</div>

var favoriteGems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gems")) || []

function changeStar(){
  if($(this).hasClass('gray-star')){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png");
    $(this).removeClass('grey-star').addClass('blue-star');
    favoriteGems.push($(this).data('info'));
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems));
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('blue-star')){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png");
    $(this).removeClass('blue-star').addClass('gray-star');
    favoriteGems = favoriteGems.filter(item => item !== $(this).data('info'));
    localStorage.setItem("gems", JSON.stringify(favoriteGems))
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#result").show();
  }
}
```

(and also maybe using a svg path for the star and controlling the color through the css class?)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and feedback!